# How to detect recurring payment transaction in PayPal

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am building a website which sells some web services. My clients will be charged monthly. I followed the document instructions ([enter link description here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/)) and after I execute the agreement. Nothing happened. After I wait for one night, I found that my test client account (sandbox account) was charged the trial amount and it said the payment is pre-approved, and my business account (sandbox account) didn't receive this payment.

So now I have the following problems about this recurring payment. Please help me about this. Thank you very much in advance.

**Q1:** How to charge initial payment in recurring payment? In my text client account, the initial payment of this recurring agreement is $0

**Q2:** How to know when the recurring payment is done? I want to record the transaction in my database and send receipt to my client after each payment.

**Updated**

I have implemented IPN to get notifications about recurring agreement created/suspended/cancelled. But I didn't find which type of notification is used after each recurring payment, and I still didn't find how to charge initial payment.

I will try using set up fee and I will post the results when the test is done.

**Update 1**

Confirmed. The set up fee is used as initial payment. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686661/paypal-recurring-payments-how-to-add-initial-payment) for more details.